# How to make a date field in Word Online?

Tags: office-365, word-online

If I open Word Online, I do not find a way to make a date field that refreshes itself at every opening. I do not want to write down the date by hand whenever I save the file on a new date. How to make the date field in Word Online?

---

In Word Desktop App (Office 365), it is clear how to make a date field, so that I have today's date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format whenever I open the file:

> Tucked away on the Insert tab is an Insert Date and Time dialog.  Insert | Text | Insert Date and Time.
>
> [image]

Taken from: [Many ways to insert the current date and time in Word](https://office-watch.com/2022/insert-current-date-time-word/)

Comment: Search the Word online resources for end-users througly. Change the title to narrow it to a single question, add what you found from your research efforts and why it didn't meet your needs. P.S. Yes Word-online doesn't support all the features of Word for Windows, so the the Word online ribbon will not show all the buttons that you see in the Word for Windows ribbon.

Comment: @Rubén I was expecting this, I also see that this is two questions in one. If I shrink it down to the question about the ribbon, I might miss another workaround that works without a ribbon. If I shrink it down to the Word online question and do not show how it is done in Word offline, I can avoid asking about the ribbons at all. Both ways could miss something. I will see whether I will take further time for this, now, I just overwrote the date :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Word Online shows the "Simplified Ribbon". To view the "Classic Ribbon", click on the **Ribbon display options**  button

[image: Ribbon display options]

then select **Classic Ribbon**

[image: Ribbon display options expanded]

Below is the Insert Tab

[image: Insert Tab]

As you can see, it doesn't include all the features that are included in Word Desktop App.

You still might try to use the Search bar to find the feature that you are looking for, but you might be wasting your time.

Another option is to look for an Add-in or to learn about Script Lab. See [Explore Office JavaScript API using Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab).

Related

- [How to change one page to landscape in Word online-browser version?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169733/88163)

Comment: Yes, tried that change to "Classic" before your answer, and it is not in there, and you do not find it in the search bar when searching for "date" or "date field". I searched again just for "field" and found that at least for headers and footers (and then, likely for the text body as well), Word online does not support putting the filename, date, author or other document properties. They tell you to use the [desktop version of Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-the-file-name-date-author-or-other-document-properties-to-a-header-or-footer-dc62245f-b6af-45b2-a521-17753fc3539e).