# How to turn off smart paragraph selection in the Microsoft Word 365 Web app?

Tags: office-365, microsoft-word, word-online, microsoft-365

How do you turn off smart paragraph selection in the Microsoft Word Web app? There are a number of questions related to this, but they all are for the desktop app, not the web app; this is an example of such a question: [How to make Microsoft Word selection behave like it would in a plain text editor](https://superuser.com/questions/962710/how-to-make-microsoft-word-selection-behave-like-it-would-in-a-plain-text-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Word Online doesn't include all the features than Word for Windows / Mac.

Microsoft includes on the feature documentation the supported editions / versions. The article about the [Word Advanced Options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/word-options-advanced-1b3d9436-bc3a-4c5d-a55f-17450e701663), wich is one of the articles related to the feature being asked, mentions the following products: Word for Microsoft 365, Word 2021, Word 2019, Word 2016, Word 2013, Word 2010, Word 2007, Word Starter 2010.

As of November 11, 2023, Microsoft refers to the Word web app / Word online as **Word for the Web**, i.e. [Create a document in Word for the web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-document-in-word-for-the-web-b406a6f9-341e-45f2-b9ac-ed85b6f7b8f6).

They have a document that compares both "platforms": [Word Features Comparison: Web vs Desktop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/word-features-comparison-web-vs-desktop-3e863ce3-e82c-4211-8f97-5b33c36c55f8). It's worth to note that this doesn't make a very detailed and exhaustive comparison.

Related

- [How to make a date field in Word Online?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169890/88163)